# Symfony % causing no route found

Tags: php, symfony, routes, url-encoding

I have a controller with a `generateQrCodeAction` in it:

```
/**
 * @Route("/qrCode/generate/{eakte}")
 * @param $eakte
 * @return Response
 */
public function generateQrCodeAction($eakte) {
    $qrService = $this->get("app.qrcode");
    $qrService->generate_qr_code($eakte);
    return new Response("done");
}
```

the eakte parameter is a url encoded one, from a string containing "/" in it. url encoding "/" results in "%2F" in the eakte parameter. However when I test the route `/qrCode/generate/800%2F08SL300001` as an example, I get a route not found error. it seems that % is not allowed in routes! is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Can't you replace the `%2F` by `/` before sending it?

Comment: then it would be a completely different route: /qrCode/generate/800/08SL300001

Comment: Sure, but with some "echapment" so `/` is considered as string? But You have an anwser that look good, hope it solve your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would allow you to have a "/" in your url parameter

```
/**
 * @Route("/qrCode/generate/{eakte}", requirements={"eakte"=".+"})
 */
```

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Answer (score 0):

For people still having this problem. I had to encode/decode the value twice for Symfony to properly accept it in the url:
When generating the url:

```php
$this->generateUrl('route_name', [
    'value' => urlencode(urlencode($value)),
]);
```

In the controller:

```php
#[Route('/route/{value}', name: 'route_name')]
public function indexByProperty(string $value): Response
{
    $decodedValue = urldecode(urldecode($value));
    // ...
}
```